# Unix string find and substitue within a file

Tags: linux, unix, replace, sed

In Unix, how do you find a pattern: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` in a file and replace it with `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: with sed (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted 3 times.  It's a pretty simple thing to do, but it's a well-worded and well-tagged question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's|([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|\1|g'
```